# Rectangle of asterisks in C

Tags: loops

Program doesn't work and I don't know why. This is my first programming course and I'm having problem with nested loops. Our activity was to create a rectangle made from asterisks using loops. I've made a code but only the loop inside the loop works. 
Here is my code

```
int main()
int a,b,i;
printf("Input length:");
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("Input width:");
scanf("%d",&b);

for(i=1;i<b;i++){
for(i=1;i<b;i++){
printf("*");}
printf("\n");}
return 0;}
```

My problem is that printf("\n") does not work in my code. Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared i twice. Change your code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;

    printf("Input length:");

    scanf("%d", &a);

    printf("Input width:");

    scanf("%d", &b);

    for(int i=1; i<b; i++)
    {
        for(int j=1; j<b; j++)
        {
            printf("*");

        }

        printf("\n");

    }

    return 0;

}
```

For printf, you need a single reference to stdio.h, which I have added to the above code.

Comment: You're very welcome. Wishing you a fantastic time C programming.